# D3 Stacked Bar Chart add Data Labels and solving D3 Label Placement

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, charts

I have two questions.

1. I want to add data labels to a stacked bar chart.
   I try to change the Code of this Example [StackedBarChart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1134768), but I am not able to add data labels.
2. if the labels are added I need to prevent overlapping. I hope I can do this like John Williams in his blog for pie charts [www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/03/11/solving-d3-label-placement-constraint-relaxing/](http://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/03/11/solving-d3-label-placement-constraint-relaxing/) or with the d3 extension D3-Labeler [//tinker10.github.io/D3-Labeler/](http:////tinker10.github.io/D3-Labeler/).

I found this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3a5Wk/1/ code and I am very grateful if you can also put the answers in a jsfiddle or explain your code in more detail as I am just starting on d3-Charts.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue of the first question by adding the Label code. I have added:

```
var dataText = svg.selectAll(".dtext")  

.data(layers)
.enter().append("g")
 .attr("class", "g")


 dataText.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter().append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x) +18; })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y + d.y0) +10; })
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .style("font-size", "10px")
  .style("color", "white")
  .text(function (d) {return (d.y);});
```

Now I still got the Problem that the labels overlap.
How can I change the position of the labels in a way that they don't overlap?